# imgradient matlab equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am searching for an `imgradient` MATLAB equivalent in Python. I am aware of  `cv2.Sobel()` and `cv2.Laplacian()` but it doesn't work as `imgradient` works in MATLAB. If I could get source code of `imgradient.m` function that would also be a great help.

Also, I know `cv2.Scharr()` can also be used but I am not sure what values should I put in parameter to get results equivalent to `imgradient` in MATLAB?

Comment: I believe my edits help with the content of your post.  I've highlighted the functions to be in code syntax.  It makes it easier to read.  Also `cv::Scharr` is part of the C++ definition but you're using Python.  That's why I've converted it to `cv2.Scharr()` instead.  Please consider keeping my edits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of copyright, we are not allowed to post any code from any of the toolboxes that you'd have to get a license for in MATLAB.  Instead what I can do is provide the code that performs the equivalent operations.  `imgradient` simply returns the magnitude and angle of the edge map.  All you need to do is apply `cv2.Sobel` in the `x` and `y` directions separately, then calculate the magnitude and angle yourself.  You can do this using the standard formulae:

```
magnitude = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2);
angle = atan2(Gy, Gx);
```

`Gx` and `Gy` are the derivatives in the `x` and `y` direction respectively, or the output of `cv2.Sobel` for each direction.  Take note that `atan2` will give you angles in radians.  MATLAB reports the angle in degrees so you'd have to additionally multiply by `180 / pi`.

Suppose your image is stored in `img`.  You'd then run `cv2.Sobel` twice on this image, ensuring that with each invocation, you specify the direction of the derivative you want to find. After that, you calculate the magnitude and angle yourself.  Therefore:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('....') # Read in the image
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0) # Find x and y gradients
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1)

# Find magnitude and angle
magnitude = np.sqrt(sobelx**2.0 + sobely**2.0)
angle = np.arctan2(sobely, sobelx) * (180 / np.pi)
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer @rayryeng. I just want to add the minor addition that instead of calling `cv2.Sobel` twice yourself one could also use the `cv2.spatialGradient` function to do this, see also here in the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga405d03b20c782b65a4daf54d233239a2)

Comment: @MuadDev very cool. Thanks!