# converting imgradient matlab equivalent in python for a more complex scenario

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, opencv

I have a problem with converting Matlab equivalent in Python.

I have a problem with the following line of code :

```
 instance_contour = uint8(imgradient(instance_map) > 0);
```

converting this line to python is the problem. As per the method suggested in [imgradient matlab equivalent in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835138/imgradient-matlab-equivalent-in-python) , I would get magnitude and angle separately, but combining them and comparing with an integer value to get a new result is the place i'm stuck. I have added the full Matlab code for reference:

```
instance_map = imread(fullfile(human_inst_root, [imname '.png']));
instance_contour = uint8(imgradient(instance_map) > 0);
imwrite(instance_contour, fullfile(output_root, [imname '.png']));
imwrite(instance_contour*255, fullfile(vis_output_root, [imname '.png']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in MATLAB that can return multiple values will only do so when you specify multiple variables to hold those values, e.g. (from the documentation for [`imgradient`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html)):

```
[Gmag,Gdir] = imgradient(I)
```

If you specify only one return variable, e.g.:

```
Gsomething = imgradient(I)
```

only the *first* return value will be stored*, in this case the magnitude. This is what is happening in the line

```
instance_contour = uint8(imgradient(instance_map) > 0);
```

There is only one (implied) return variable that is used in the logical comparison, so you're only really comparing the magnitude of the gradient to `0`. There is no need to try to combine this with the direction.

<sub>* You can choose *which* variable to return using the `~` to skip values similar to the `_` in Python. `[~,Gdir] = imgradient(I)` would return only the second return value from the function.</sub>